# error: ‘class std::vector<route, std::allocator<route> >’ has no member named ‘exitPoint’

Tags: c++, vector

Please tell me if some more info is needed here:
Global declarations:

```
    typedef struct route
    {
        int          exitPoint;
        bool         allBranchesTraversed;
    } route;

   ****vector <route> routeVector;****
```

The culprit func is getting called from:

```
int main ()
{
....
    do
    {
        ****currentExitPoint = returnShortestWeightedBranch (&routeVector);****
        if (currentExitPoint != -1)
        {
            objRoute.exitPoint = currentExitPoint;          
            routeVector.push_back (objRoute);
        }
        else
        {
          break;
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

The error is in this func on the line with ******:

```
int returnShortestWeightedBranch (vector <route> *objRouteVector)
{
....    
    for (unsigned int h = 0; h < objRouteVector->size (); h++)
    {
        // Locate 'currentExitPoint' in the vector 'exitPointDetailsVector'.
        for (i = 0; i < exitPointDetailsVector.size(); i++)
        {       
            // If located
            ****if (objRouteVector[h].exitPoint == exitPointDetailsVector[i].exitPoint)****
            {
                // For all the branches of the 'currentExitPoint',
                for (j = 0; j < exitPointDetailsVector[i].branchesVector.size(); j++)
                {

...............
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `vector <route> *objRouteVector` as parameter, you need `(*objRouteVector)[h].exitPoint`. Better is using reference: `vector <route> &objRouteVector`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, and now if I write `vector <route> &objRouteVector` how am I supposed to access it? The way you have shown above will work for this reference too?

Comment: @Anisha: Access it just like normal. With references there is no extra syntax for access to the underlying object.

Answer (score 2):

You took a pointer to objRouteVector, you need to take a reference. Your code indexing objRouteVector isn't indexing the vector at all- it's indexing the *pointer*.

Comment: So how should I have written that?

Comment: @Anisha Kaul: You need to take a reference and your code should work without modification, except at the call site where you need to not take the address.